# FragmentTransaction se lleva contenido del fragment anterior

Tags: android, material-design

Buenas tardes.

Estoy usando tabs, bottomnavigation; **mi problema es que cuando voy desde un tab a una opción del BottomNavigation, el contenido del fragmento del tab se sigue quedando en la pantalla.**

Este es el xml donde se encuentra todo, el TabLayout y el BOTTOMNAVIGATION(BottomBar).

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/BarLayout"
      android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    >

        <include
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
             app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
             android:id="@+id/include" />


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/TabLayout"
           app:tabMode="fixed"
           app:tabGravity="fill"
           app:tabTextColor="@color/blanco"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/blanco"
         />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




 <FrameLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/frame"         
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
     />


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ViewPager"
    android:layout_below="@+id/BarLayout"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />

<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/Bar"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs"
    app:bb_behavior="shifting"
    app:bb_showShadow="true"
    app:bb_activeTabColor="#fff"
    android:layout_below="@id/ViewPager"
    />
```

Este es mi activity donde está el codigo para pasar de fragment y más.

```
public class Activity_Inicio extends AppCompatActivity {

BottomBar bar;
Toolbar toolbar;
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
private AdaptadorViewPager adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity__inicio);


    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.include);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.TabLayout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.ViewPager);
    bar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.Bar);


    adapter = new AdaptadorViewPager(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.AdaptadorViewPager(new FragmentLapidas(), "Lápidas");
    adapter.AdaptadorViewPager(new FragmentLozas(), "Lozas");
    adapter.AdaptadorViewPager(new FragmentTazas(), "Tazas");


    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);



    bar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction trans = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


            switch (tabId){

                case R.id.tab_home:

                    FragmentHome home = new FragmentHome();
                    trans.replace(R.id.frame, home).commit();
                    toolbar.setTitle("Fotocerámica");
                    tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    break;

                case R.id.tab_videos:

                    FragmentVideos videos = new FragmentVideos();
                    trans.replace(R.id.frame, videos).commit();
                    toolbar.setTitle("Videos");
                    tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    break;

                case R.id.tab_testi:

                    FragmentTestimonios testimonios = new FragmentTestimonios();
                    trans.replace(R.id.frame, testimonios).commit();
                    toolbar.setTitle("Testimonios");
                    tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    break;

                case R.id.tab_info:

                    FragmentInfo info = new FragmentInfo();
                    trans.replace(R.id.frame, info).commit();
                    toolbar.setTitle("Información");
                    tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    break;


            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Cuando voy desde una opción del BottomNav a otra opción del BottomNav funciona correctamente; entonces resumiendo mi consulta, este sería: **Cómo arreglar eso, me refiero a que el contenido del fragment del tab que selecciono ya no se quede cuando seleccione una opción del BottomNavigation.**

Espero haberme explicado bien.

**Les dejo un ejemplo**

El "Hello blank fragment" es el contenido de un tab y el "info" es el contenido  de la opción "Info" del BottonNav.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Despues de la transacción del Fragment usa  [addToBackStack(null)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String))  para que no agregue ningun Fragment al "backstack" :

```
trans.addToBackStack(null);
```

con esto al realizar una transacción le indicas que no sea guardada en el backstack, considero que es probable que almacena una sobre otra por eso ves contenido de la anterior al realizar una nueva transacción.

Comment: Con respecto a esta respuesta alguien me agrego calificación negativa, @JorgeRequez quisiera saber si realizaste este cambio?